# Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" pecl packages are unreachable

Tags: php, windows, oracle

I'm trying to use pecl, but everytime I got this error message. I don't have xampp. I don't have any apache, I'm using only the built in php server. So I don't have xampp directory, it's only C:\php for me. Now I edited the php.ini file, I removed the semicolon from the extension openssl, but it's still erroring. Do I have to download any OpenSSL directory? I tried, but it's only a git repository, what needs a lot of other applications to run... I don't know if I really need to download Embarcadero C++, and MinGV? That seems too complicated to me... I wanted to use some packages, like php memcache, and oci, but for that I had to install pear (it was NOT included in php), then install pecl, then I have to install these C++ apps, and MinGV to run OpenSSL to be able to download pecl packages? No way...
Windows 10 64x
PHP 8.0.12

Comment: What errors are you getting

Comment: Connection to `ssl://pecl.php.net:443' failed: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install OpenSSL windows client?
Please install OpenSSL and set php.ini by

```
OPENSSL_CONF=LOCATION_OF_SSL_INSTALL\bin\openssl.cfg
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have only the "openssl.cafile=" and "openssl.capath=" lines in the php.ini. Should I add a new row for the php.ini file with this line? And I installed OpenSSL, and it has a bin directory, but there's not any openssl.cfg file...